# TIBCO JMS Listener in esb microservice

Tags: wso2, jms, jndi, tibco

I try to configure TIBCO JMS listener in microesb (from Integration Studio)

added some lines in \runtime\microesb\conf\deployment.toml :

```
[[transport.jms.listener]]
parameter.initial_naming_factory = "com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsInitialContextFactory"
parameter.provider_url = "tibjmsnaming://_hostname_:7222"
parameter.connection_factory_name = "QueueConnectionFactory"
```

when try to run simple application - got this error:

```
ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.BaseUtils} - JNDI lookup of name QueueConnectionFactory returned a com.tibco.tibjms.naming.TibjmsFederatedQueueConnectionFactory while a interface javax.jms.ConnectionFactory was expected
```

What am I doing wrong?
Tibco EMS 8.5, all 5 jar files from EMS copied to \runtime\microesb\wso2\components\extensions

Comment: Can you also add `parameter.connection_factory_type = "queue"` and check

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check the type of your QueueConnectionFactory connection factory.

Is it defined with type 'queue' or 'generic' ?

you can check this in EMS factories.conf file like below :
[QueueConnectionFactory]

type                     = queue